# How get data from database to Drop down list in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, select, dropdown

I have created drop down list and i want to add "selected" value according to the database.

This is dynamic and must be embedded in html table. but i am unable to complete this code.

My requirment as belows.

one parent can have more than one child and their educational level can be vary. According to that i have used three fields name called NIC number, child_name and status. There are three possible status called Currently Studying,Completed and To be enter.

According to that unable to select status value as per database value.

```
<?php
$nic=$_GET['nic'];
                                            include '../svr/connection.php';
                                            $query1 = "Select * from child where nic='$nic'";
                                            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
                                            $x = 100;
                                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                                echo "<tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox'></td>

         <td>
         <div class='search-box'>
         <input type='text'class='form-control' value='{$row['child_name']}' name='item_name[]' id='item_$x'>
         <div class='res'></div>
         </div></td>


        <td>
<select name='study[]' id='study_$x' class='form-control'>
              <option value='Currently Studying'>Currently Studying</option>
              <option value='Completed studies'>Completed</option>
              <option value='To Be Studied'> To Be Enter</option>
 </select>        

</td>
</tr>";
```

Comment: Try `...class='form-control' value='{" . $row['child_name'] . "}' name=...`

Comment: This method is unable to use because i want to show database value as selected value in drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

You have a drop-down with three pre-filled options. Your database entry will have any one of these options. Now you want to select the value that is fetched from the database based on the record.

I am assuming that you are landing on this page from the previous page that gave you the `$nic` using `$_GET`.

You will use JS to achieve this. Refer to the below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#study').val("<?php echo $your_fetched_value; ?>");     
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps.